# @onmouseup not firing at vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, onmouseup

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_vue_simple_audio_1

I attach `@onmouseup` to `input range`. When I drag the slider, `progressChange` seems not be called.

```
<input 
  type="range"
  :min="0" 
  :step="1"
  v-model="current"

  :value="current"
  :max="duration"
  @onmouseup="progressChange()"
  />
```

Here is the `methods`

```
methods: {
    timeChange: function () {
      this.current = this.$refs.player.currentTime;
    },
    getDuration: function () {
      this.duration = this.$refs.player.duration;
    },
    toggleStatus: function () {
      var player = this.$refs.player;
      this.isPause ? player.play() : player.pause();
      this.isPause = !this.isPause;
    },
    next: function () {
      if (this.audioIndex == this.songs.length - 1) {
        if (this.repeat) {
          this.audioIndex = 0;
        }
      } else {
        this.audioIndex++;
      }
    },
    prev: function () {
      if (this.audioIndex == 0) {
        if (this.repeat) {
          this.audioIndex = this.songs.length - 1;
        }
      } else {
        this.audioIndex--;
      }
    },
    progressChange() {
      console.log("progress change");
    },
```

Comment: For future - please in such kind of case - answer your own question. I posted an answer to fully clarify the issue as some day people can be looking for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer this question for future reference for people who would be looking for similar issues:

The issue was the wrong name on calling event as VueJS uses syntax of `@even` where `@` replaces 'on`, so you have to use:

- @mouseup
- @click
- @keyup:keyname
- @input
- @customEventEmitedByComponent